# expression containing radicals of imaginary numbers

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I can't bear an expression containing radicals of imaginary numbers,
in case it can be expressed as in terms of radicals of real numbers only.

For example, I can't bear the expression

```
Sqrt[2 + I]
```

because
it can be expressed as

```
Sqrt[1/2 (2 + Sqrt[5])] + Sqrt[1/2 (-2 + Sqrt[5])] I
```

But it seems there is no easy way to do it in Mathematica. I have tried many commands (in Mathematica) but all in vain.

Is there a systematic way to do such job ?

`Sqrt[2 + I]` was a very simple example. I hope the method work for much more complicated expression.

P.S
I know that there are many algebraic numbers that cannot be expressed as in terms of radicals, For example, `Root[#^5 + # - 1 &, 1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{1, I}.(Sqrt[2 + I] // ReIm // ComplexExpand // FunctionExpand // 
   FullSimplify)

(* I Sqrt[1/2 (-2 + Sqrt[5])] + Sqrt[1/2 (2 + Sqrt[5])] *)
```

or

```
% // Simplify

(* (I Sqrt[-2 + Sqrt[5]] + Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]])/Sqrt[2] *)
```

Verifying that these are equivalent to the original form

```
Sqrt[2 + I] === (% // FullSimplify) === (%% // FullSimplify)

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Four commands in a row!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sqrt[2 + I] // ComplexExpand // FunctionExpand
```

It may not create a result simplified in the exact form you want, but it will be closer.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility:

```
ComplexExpand[Sqrt[2 + I], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // FunctionExpand // Simplify
   (5^(1/4) ((2 + I) + Sqrt[5]))/Sqrt[10 + 4 Sqrt[5]]
```